# Runtime 424 - Object Required in Access 2013

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am trying to cycle through a set of Access form fields in order to identify last value and then build a calculation around it.  The code for the first line is as below:

```
Private Sub TierCalc_Click()

Dim lastStageValue As Integer

    If (CP6Sum.Value Is Not Null) Then
        lastStageValue = CP6Sum.Value
    End If


End Sub
```

When I run this, I get the above '424 Runtime Object required' error.
If I take out the '.Value' in the code as suggested by other sites it stays the same.
If I declare the field (i.e. 'Dim CP6Sum As Integer') I get 'Invalid Qualifier' and if I then take the '.value' out I get 'Type Mismatch' error??

Any ideas please?
Thanks,
Lisa

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Private Sub TierCalc_Click()
Dim lastStageValue As Integer

If Not IsNull(Me.CP6Sum) Then
    lastStageValue = CP6Sum.value
End If


End Sub
```

Comment: That's worked a treat thanks.  Could you tell me what the 'Me.' signifies please (as you can tell I'm a complete beginner!)

Comment: @Leecey5225, in this instance "me" refers to the form that has focus and is currently running code.  You can use either the form name that contains the button 'TierCalc' or 'me' in this scenario -- me acts like an implicitly declared variable.